# cant get rid of scrollbar

Tags: html, scrollbar

so far this is the code, but unfortunately i can't get rid of the scroll bar on the side of the page

```
<font style= "padding: 1rem; left: 0px; top: 0px; width:100%; color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1) !important; line-height:0.7em; font-family: System; font-size: 15px !important;display: block !important; position: absolute; min-height:45rem; box-sizing: border-box; background-image:url('https://i.postimg.cc/05J8rfpL/fe78bbb25f35d56b502327fb6d43b309-1.jpg'); background-repeat: repeat; background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center; overflow: hidden;">


<div style="visibility:hidden;">
```

Comment: The `<font>` tag is deprecated

Comment: @SuperStormer im not sure what that means !

Comment: Don't use it, it has been removed from html5 and is only supported in browsers for back-compatibility

Comment: okay then what should i use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding the overflow: hidden on the body element?

Comment: You can use the browsers developer tool to check which element shows the scrollbar. You can hit f12 and inspect the elements. Then add the overflow:hidden on that element.

Comment: f12 is airplane mode on my laptop. if by inspect the elements you mean checking the source, tried that :(